# Speeding up a complex python dataframe transposition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I've got three tables. I need to manipulate table 1 and 2 to get table 3.

Table 1

| GENEID | person_1 | person_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ENSG001 | 0.01 | 1.6 |
| ENSG002 | 1.25 | -2.2 |

Table 2

| ENSG | Chromosome | EntrezGene | GeneSymbol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ENSG001 | 1 | 001 | Symbol1 |
| ENSG002 | 2 | 002 | Symbol2 |

Table 3

| GENEID | GeneSymbol | EntrezGene | person_id | expression |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ENSG001 | Symbol1 | 001 | person_1 | 0.01 |
| ENSG002 | Symbol2 | 002 | person_1 | 1.25 |
| ENSG001 | Symbol1 | 001 | person_2 | 1.6 |
| ENSG002 | Symbol2 | 002 | person_2 | -2.2 |

I've got code that does this. But it is unacceptably slow on large files. I'm dealing with files averaging about 800 columns wide and 60,000 rows deep. I'm not sure how to speed it up.

```
import pandas as pd
import tqdm

filenames = ["filename1", "filename2"]

merge_file = pd.read_csv("mergefile_123.tsv", sep="\t", dtype='str')

def rearrange_dataframe(df):
    """Transpose the dataframe so that the person_ids are the index, and the columns are the ensembleIds"""
    df_new_index = df.set_index('GENEID').copy()
    transpose_df = df_new_index.T
    return transpose_df

def create_fixed_gene_df(trans_df):
    concat_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for index, rows in trans_df.iterrows():
        new_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data = {"GENEID":rows.index.tolist(), "person_id":[rows.name] * len(rows.index), "expression":rows.values})
        if concat_df.empty:
            concat_df = new_dataframe
        else:   
            concat_df = pd.concat([concat_df, new_dataframe])
    return concat_df



for f in tqdm.tqdm(filenames):
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep="\t", dtype='str')

    transposed_df = rearrange_dataframe(df)
    fixed_gene_df = create_fixed_gene_df(transposed_df)
    merge_symbol_df = fixed_gene_df.merge(merge_df[["ENSG","EntrezGene ID","HGNC symbol"]],
                               left_on="GENEID", right_on="ENSG",how="left")
    renamed_df = merge_symbol_df.rename(columns={"EntrezGene ID":"locus", "HGNC symbol":"geneSymbol"})
    final_df = renamed_df[["GENEID","geneSymbol","locus","person_id","expression"]]
    final_df.to_csv("{}_transposed_file.tsv".format(f.split(".tsv")[0]),sep="\t",index=False)
```

Any tips on how to optimize the manipulations would be really helpful. And any resources I can read up on so I can get better at these would be great too. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to join `df1` and `df2` on `GENEID` then [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) to get the data into long form:

```
df3 = (
    df1.merge(
        df2[['ENSG', 'EntrezGene', 'GeneSymbol']]  # Select columns from df2
            .rename(columns={'ENSG': 'GENEID'}),  # Rename merge column to match
        on='GENEID'
    ).melt(
        id_vars=['GENEID', 'GeneSymbol', 'EntrezGene'],  # Columns to duplicate
        var_name='person_id',  # New column header for previous column names
        value_name='expression'  # New column header for previous data values
    )
)
```

`df3`:

```
    GENEID GeneSymbol EntrezGene person_id  expression
0  ENSG001    Symbol1        001  person_1        0.01
1  ENSG002    Symbol2        002  person_1        1.25
2  ENSG001    Symbol1        001  person_2        1.60
3  ENSG002    Symbol2        002  person_2       -2.20
```

---

DataFrames and import:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'GENEID': ['ENSG001', 'ENSG002'], 'person_1': [0.01, 1.25],
    'person_2': [1.6, -2.2]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ENSG': {0: 'ENSG001', 1: 'ENSG002'}, 'Chromosome': {0: 1, 1: 2},
    'EntrezGene': {0: '001', 1: '002'},
    'GeneSymbol': {0: 'Symbol1', 1: 'Symbol2'}
})
```

Comment: This worked. It's frighteningly faster than my original implementation. 19.42 minutes for 16.7 second (69.77 times increase?) for a single file Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `melt` on `df1` before merging:

```
>>> df1.melt(id_vars='GENEID', value_vars=['person_1', 'person_2'],  
             var_name='person_id', value_name='expression') \
       .merge(df2, left_on='GENEID', right_on='ENSG') \
       .drop(columns='ENSG')

    GENEID person_id  expression  Chromosome  EntrezGene GeneSymbol
0  ENSG001  person_1        0.01           1           1    Symbol1
1  ENSG001  person_2        1.60           1           1    Symbol1
2  ENSG002  person_1        1.25           2           2    Symbol2
3  ENSG002  person_2       -2.20           2           2    Symbol2
```

Answer (score 3):

Rework df1 with [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
df1b = pd.melt(df1, id_vars=['GENEID'], var_name='person_id', value_name='expression')
```

Then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) with df2:

```
df2.merge(df1b, left_on='ENSG', right_on='GENEID').drop(columns='ENSG')
```